# How to show a div hovering on it

Tags: html, css

I want the div .disco-sopra to show when you hover on it. I literally tried EVERYTHING. It's probably something with the many z-index's I'm using but I don't know what to do. It's all here: http://jsfiddle.net/172ja79b/

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="disco-lionheart">
<div class="disco-sopra">
<a href=""><div class="disco-table2">
<div class="disco-link"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
</div>
</a>
</div>

<div class="disco-sotto">
<div class="disco-table"><div class="disco-table-testo">
<div class="disco-anno">2015</div>
          <div class="disco-title">Lion Heart</div>
<div class="disco-info"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 19 agosto 2015<span class="Block"></span><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> 12 tracce</div>

</div></div>
</div>

<div class="ombra"></div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS code:

```
.disco-lionheart {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background-position: top center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
  background-image:url(http://www.girlsgenerationitalia.it/wp-content/themes/ggi1/media/img/discografia/lionheart-500.jpg);
}

.disco-anno {
  vertical-align: middle;
background-color: #fff;
font-size: 13pt;
padding: 2px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
color: #fff;
background-image:url(http://www.girlsgenerationitalia.it/wp-content/themes/ggi1/media/img/discografia/bgdisco.jpg);
background-position:center;
font-weight: 800;
z-index: 10000000;
margin: auto;
width: 43px;
}

.disco-table {
display:table;
width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
z-index: 1;
}

.disco-title {
  font-size: 19pt;
  line-height: 21pt;
  font-weight: 300;
  color:#fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;

  z-index: 10000000;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);

}

.disco-table-testo {
display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
}

.disco-link {
display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
z-index: 1111119999492848683824;
font-size: 150px;
}

.disco-table2 {
display:table;
width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
z-index: 1111111111111111;

}

.disco-sopra {
display:none;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 9999999999999898989898989898989898989898;
}

.disco-sotto {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 99999999999;
}

.disco-sopra:hover {
display:inline;
}

.disco-info {
  z-index: 1000000000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.disco-info i, .disco-link i {
  color: #fff;
}

.disco-info a:link, .disco-info a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}

.ombra {
  background-image:url(http://girlsgenerationitalia.it/wp-content/themes/ggi1/media/img/ombra.png);
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  z-index: -1
}
```

Comment: Reason is you can not call the parent from hovering the child, while reverse is possible. So i guess only  possible way is using JavaScript/JQuery.

Comment: what do you want particularly, i think i might have solution, just with CSS. NO JavaScript/JQuery.

Comment: If I am reading this right, you want to display a div when it is hovered over? First of all, you can not hover a div if you are not displaying it. You could do manage to do this with opacity depending on what you need exactly.

Comment: thank u everybody! I used opacity and it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/172ja79b/2/

My fiddle isn't really good design but it does work.

There are 2 mistakes here:

1. disco-sopra doesn't have printable content (or height and width), so even if the hover event was triggered, nothing would happen.
2. pointing to a space that isn't rendered is rather difficult

So I put something in sopra and created a CSS line:

```
.disco-lionheart:hover .disco-sopra { display: inline; }
```

This way if the parent element get's a hover it triggers

Answer (score 1):

You can not hover an element that is not being displayed. As long as you have `display: none` set for your div, you can not hover over it.

You have two options; either watch hover on a parent element to display the child or use the opacity css attribute to display the element without the user seeing it. When you set it to 0, the element will still be there so it can be hovered over but unless the user hovers over it, it will be invisible.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
div span {
  color: white;
}
.hover-to-see {
  opacity: 0;
}
.hover-to-see:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover-to-see">
  <span>Magic!</span>
</div>
<p>Hover above to see the magic!</p>
```